# Windows 7 Professional Cannot Connect to Share - Wrong password

Tags: windows-7, server-message-block

I know that this question has actually been asked a few times before, but every solution I found didn't yield any results on my end, I can't get my head around it: 
When I am trying to connect to a share on the network, I always get the response "The specified network password is incorrect". However, the password is definetly correct and it works if I connect from another machine. I changed the LAN Manager authentication level to "Send LM & NTLM - use NTLMv2 session security if negiotated", I configured Kerberos encryption types to include all suites, rebooted (several times), but still - no luck. 
I can connect if I use my regular account with which I am logged in, but I need to connect with a different user since my log-in user has not enough privileges on the share. When I do that, the error above comes up.

I'm really frustrated at the moment, this problem is driving me crazy. I'd be gladful for any possible solution to this. At the moment I'm using a workaround: I connect to a different machine via RDP, login with the user I have to use for the network-share connection and then I can map the drive and copy/paste from the RDP session to my local workstation. This is also working when I am connecting via RDP with my current login user and map the drive with the other user who has sufficent privileges.

Comment: Did you try to reset or override network credentials on a client machine as described here: http://superuser.com/questions/556084/reset-stored-windows-7-file-sharing-password ?

Comment: What is the network share? A unix file share? A hard drive attached to a router? A NAS box (What brand?)? A windows server? A windows desktop?  Is the box that works correctly a windows 7 pro box as well? Are you on a domain?  Are they in the same OU?  How are the two boxes different? Can't really provide any answers without more information.

Answer (score 0):

A few steps can be taken here to find out the actual cause -

If your share is hosted on a windows machine.  try to access share from client and once you get the incorrect password error.  You should access the machine where share is hosted and look at the security logs in Event Viewer and see what message you are getting there.This will help in catching the root cause.  In this way this will also make sure that you are reaching to correct server or not.  One more thing I would suggest is to do a arp lookup using command below -

arp -a

Then match the mac for share hosted machine on the client and as well as on server. This will ensure about the updated mac table on client.